# "At least one object must implement IComparable" exception from LINQ query results

Tags: excel, vb.net, linq

I have not used LINQ very extensively, but I'm trying to read data from a large Excel spreadsheet (14K+ rows) that requires me to make queries from multiple worksheets and even requery the original spreadsheet to filter specific data.  Because OleDb queries of Excel can take a relatively long time (500+ms per query for a file on my local machine), I'm doing a couple of these queries at the front of my method, starting a loop through a "base" DataTable, then trying to use LINQ to filter down the data within that loop to put the appropriate data into a more structured DataSet.  Here is some code to help explain (VB.NET):

```
Dim Connection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim Command As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_1 As New DataTable
Dim EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_2 As New DataTable
Dim EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_3 As New DataTable
Dim TapeFile As New FileInfo("C:\TempFolder\tapefile.xls")

Connection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" & TapeFile.FullName & "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
Command = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SHEET1$] ORDER BY [USER_ID] ASC, [MEMBER_NUMBER] ASC;", Connection)
Command.Fill(EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_1)
Command.Dispose()

Command = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SHEET2$] ORDER BY [USER_ID] ASC, [MEMBER_NUMBER] ASC;", Connection)
Command.Fill(EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_2)
Command.Dispose()

Command = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SHEET3$] ORDER BY [USER_ID] ASC, [MEMBER_NUMBER] ASC;", Connection)
Command.Fill(EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_3)
Command.Dispose()

For Each Row As DataRow In EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_1.Rows
    Dim MemberNumber As String = Row("MEMBER_NUMBER").ToString.Trim
    Dim UserNumber As String = Row("USER_ID").ToString.Trim

' -- CODE FOR INITIAL PROCESSING OF SHEET1 DATA - NO ERRORS --

    Dim CoMemberQuery As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = From cm In EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_2 Where cm("MEMBER_NUMBER") = MemberNumber And cm("USER_ID") = UserNumber

    For Each CoMemberRow As DataRow In CoMemberQuery

' -- CODE FOR PROCESSING OF SHEET2 DATA - NO ERRORS --

    Next CoMemberRow

    Dim VehicleQuery As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = From veh In EXCEL_SHEET_DATA_1 Where veh("MEMBER_NUMBER") = MemberNumber And veh("USER_ID") = UserNumber Order By veh("VIN") Ascending

' *******************************************************
' -->> HERE IS WHERE I *SOMETIMES* GET THE EXCEPTION <<--
' *******************************************************
    For Each VehicleRow As DataRow In VehicleQuery
' -- CODE FOR SECONDARY PROCESSING OF SHEET1 DATA - NO ERRORS --
    Next VehicleRow
Next Row
```

I don't get the exception every time.  The only thing I've noticed as possibly having something to do with it is that for the specific `MemberNumber` and `UserNumber` combination that causes the first exception, the first row in the result set would most likely contain a NULL value for the VIN field.

I'm sure the problem has to do with my LINQ query syntax, but I am simply too inexperienced in this regard to know why it's failing.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  If you require any additional information regarding the code or implementation, let me know and I'll try to add it to the question. 
 Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VehicleQuery has the following phrase: `Order By veh("VIN") Ascending`.

So as soon as `VehicleQuery` gets evaluated (by starting the `For` loop), LINQ will evaluate all of the items in that query, and then perform a sorting operation, which involves comparing the `veh("VIN")` values with each other and putting them in order.

When comparing any two items in your query, it tries to see if either value knows how to compare itself with values of the other type (hence implementing the `IComparable` interface. If they cannot, then it doesn't know which one should go first.

My guess is that `veh("VIN")` is (sometimes) yielding objects that don't know how to compare themselves with other values returned by this expression. Depending on the kind of data you're using, and how you want it to be compared, you might consider doing some kind of cast or conversion, or simply calling `ToString()` on the value, to make sure it's comparable: `Order By veh("VIN").ToString() Ascending`

(Please pardon any syntax errors, as I'm a C# developer.)

Comment: Holy crap!  That seems to have worked!  Thank you SO much!  I'm a bit upset with myself for not coming up with that solution myself, considering it's simplicity, but it seems to be running without error now.  I was concerned that it might balk trying to cast NULL values from the DataTable to Strings, but it seems to have made it through the entire group of DataTables without any further error (and a lot faster than when I was doing multiple OleDb queries).